# Angularjs $http.post, long operations on server with PHP

Tags: php, json, angularjs, amazon-s3

I have a web app that runs PHP, MySQL server side (on Amazon EC2, with S3 storage), and in the client - JS/AngularJS.
With the app, users can send a "postcard" to the server. A postcard is a form that includes some text and a couple of pictures that the user uploads. 
After filling all the details and pushing "submit", the postcard is sent: 
 - The files are uploaded to a temp folder, and their new temp names are returned to the client. 
 - When this process is completed, another $http.post request is sent to
   the server with all of the postcard's information, including an array
   of the images' temp names.
 - The new postcard data is written in the DB, with a STATUS and PERCENT fields.
 - The images are converted to a smaller format and then saved to S3. The 'postcard' DB entry is updated (STATUS = 'saving photos', PERCENT = 40%)
 - Images table is updated with the new images' IDs. 'postcard' DB entry updated (STATUS = 'last finishes', PERCENT = 90%).
- a JSON response is sent to the client. 'postcard' DB entry updated (STATUS = 'completed', PERCENT = 100%).

The problem is that between sending "submit" and receiving the JSON response - that takes a lot of time. 
Photos are uploaded to the tmp folder pretty quickly, but the rest of the process takes more than 20 seconds. During that time I present a "Loading" screen with a progress bar, which is updated by polling the server for the postcard's status and percentage fields in the postcards DB.
I would like the process to be different - the user uploads the photos and then can go back to navigating the app, while the rest of the process is happening on the server, and a message (success/failure) will be sent when the process is done... 
So how should I approach this?
How can I return a response from the PHP side after receiving all the necessary information from the user? and continue to run the heavier operations on the server? how do I send back a response to the user when the process is complete, and how can the client "catch" it?
Thanks.

This is the current function on the server (Im using code igniter). The function gets the JSON object sent on "submit", then sends the data to my postcard_model where all of the Data saving/image processing takes places). The response is only sent after all of these operations are completed, and that takes 20-60 seconds, while the user is waiting and the user interface is not responsive. I would like that changed - getting an immediate response that the data was received, and after a minute getting another message saying that the process is complete.

```
    public function save(){

    $data = $this->input->get_post('postcard');
    $cleanData = json_decode($data);

    try {
        $response = $this->postcard_model->save($cleanData);
        $this->json->response(array(
            'success' => $response,
        ));
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $this->json->error($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically you need advice on? It seems like you have all the processing and working code, just not clear what you want help with now. Sounds like all you need is some sort of indicator in a navbar for example showing something like "Files pending" and a notification when the amazon processing succeeds ( or fails)

Comment: Hi, I edited the question:
So how should I approach this? How can I return a response from the PHP side after receiving all the necessary information from the user? and continue to run the heavier operations on the server? how do I send back a response to the user when the process is complete, and how can the client "catch" it? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just have a directive right in the body outside of  `ng-view` where user can see progress while they navigate ? Use same polling you were doing before but not blocking the UI while it's going on

Comment: The problem isn't simply giving feedback to the user. While I'm waiting for the response to the ajax call which produces the "heavy" operation, other ajax calls can't be made (or they take a lot of time to complete), and that doesn't really allow the user to keep on using the app.

Comment: I understand that...which is why I made suggestion above about directive that lets user navigate and shows progress. Not much different than the way browsers do it with download status